# URL changes into dot instead of slash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am building an reservation system therefore a user can view their trips. A reservation belongs_to a room and a room has_may reservations so @room is a foreign key. I want to link the image of a room to the show room view. However when I click on the link, the URL is changing to c9users.io/**rooms.1** instead of c9users.io/**rooms/1**.

**What steps are necessary to make this work?**

**What is causing this behavior?**

It does not look like a pluralization error because I also have tried:

```
<%= link_to room_path(trip.room) do %>
```

Unfortunately the result is the same.

**your_trips.html.erb**

```
<% @trips.each do |trip| %>
        <%= link_to rooms_path(trip.room) do %>
            <div>
                <%= image_tag trip.room.photos[0].image.url(:thumb) if trip.room.photos.length > 0 %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#welcome'

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :users,
             :path => '',
             :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :edit => 'profile'},
             :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth_callbacks'}

  get 'rentout' => 'static_pages#rentout'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'impressum' => 'static_pages#impressum'

  resources :rooms, only: [:index, :show]
  resources :photos

  resources :rooms do 
    resources :reservations, only: [:create]
  end

  get '/preload' => 'reservations#preload'
  get '/preview' => 'reservations#preview'

  get '/your_trips' => 'reservations#your_trips'
end
```

**reservations_controller.rb**

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def preload
        room = Room.find(params[:room_id])
        today = Date.today
        reservations = room.reservations.where("start_date >= ? OR end_date >= ?", today, today)

        render json: reservations
    end

    def preview
        start_date = Date.parse(params[:start_date])
        end_date = Date.parse(params[:end_date])

        output = {
            conflict: is_conflict(start_date, end_date)
        }

        render json: output
    end

    def create
        @room = Room.find(params[:room_id])
        @reservation = current_user.reservations.create(reservation_params.merge(room_id: @room.id))
        redirect_to @reservation.room, notice: "Your reservation has been created"
    end

    def your_trips
        @trips = current_user.reservations
    end

    private
        def is_conflict(start_date, end_date)
            room = Room.find(params[:room_id])

            check = room.reservations.where("? < start_date AND end_date < ?", start_date, end_date)
            check.size > 0? true : false
        end

        def reservation_params
            params.require(:reservation).permit(:start_date, :end_date, :price, :total, :room_id)
        end
end
```

**rooms_controller.rb**

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_room, only: [:show]

  def index
    @rooms = Room.all
  end

  def show
    @photos = @room.photos
  end

  private
    def set_room
      @room = Room.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

I am using Rails 5.0.1 with Cloud9 IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have the `rooms` resource defined twice:

```
resources :rooms, only: [:index, :show]
resources :photos

resources :rooms do 
  resources :reservations, only: [:create]
end
```

You can consolidate that:

```
resources :photos

resources :rooms, only: [:index, :show] do 
  resources :reservations, only: [:create]
end
```

I'm not 100% sure that will fix your issue, but it's the first thing I'd try.

Comment: Thanks allot this drove me nuts! I had to change then the  <%= link_to rooms_path(trip.room) do %> into singular <%= link_to room_path(trip.room) do %> and now it works like a charm! ;) Thank you again!

Comment: Oh, I didn't see anything about `rooms_path` in your question. If you used the pluralized `rooms_path`, your `room.id` gets applied to the optional `format` placeholder in the index route. (Usually `format` is used for file extensions like `xml`, `json`, `js`, `pdf`, etc., as in `rooms_path(:csv)` => `/rooms.csv`.) Hope that makes sense.